# Weird results using Search After () elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

i am having issues with search after api in elastic search.
please see this link where i posted the full description of the problem

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/weird-results-using-search-after-elastic-search/116609?u=ayshwarya_sree

Comment: Please always post the full question in stack overflow too, instead of links as links can break in future. Which won't be helpful for people looking at it after some time

Comment: okay..will keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [searchAfter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html)

> A field with one unique value per document should be used as the
>   tiebreaker of the sort specification. Otherwise the sort order for
>   documents that have the same sort values would be undefined. The
>   recommended way is to use the field _id which is certain to contain
>   one unique value for each document.

Since you are only passing gender as sorting criteria, on your next second request it assumes that you are expecting results after Female, which will be results with gender Male.

Try adding _id as sort and searchafter parameter too

Comment: SearchResponse sr = ts.prepareSearch("acc")
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(field.toLowerCase()).from(from).to(to))
    .addSort("_id", SortOrder.ASC)
    .addSort(sort_param.toLowerCase(), SortOrder.ASC)
    .get();                                                                                                          is the code i wrote but now its not working sort is not taking place @Aman B

Comment: i even tried using my unique id field instead of "_id" but it still gives only female after male

Comment: If your elastic search version is before v6, then use _uid instead of _id because its not an indexed field in older versions https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-id-field.html